# rails admin uninitialized constant Country::Person

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

When I click on Countries in rails_admin navigation I get

```
NameError in RailsAdmin::Main#index

uninitialized constant Country::Person

raise NameError.new("uninitialized constant #{candidates.first}", candidates.first)
```

I'm using User model but not Person. I think I need to configure it somehow. But where to do this?

here's my rails admin initializer

```
  ## == Devise ==
   config.authenticate_with do
     warden.authenticate! scope: :user
   end
   config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  ## == Cancan ==
   config.authorize_with :cancan 

  ### More at https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Base-configuration

  config.model "User" do
      edit do
        field :admin
        field :username
        field :email
        field :password
      end
    end

  config.actions do
    dashboard                     # mandatory
    index                         # mandatory
    new
    export
    bulk_delete
    show
    edit
    delete
    show_in_app

    ## With an audit adapter, you can add:
    # history_index
    # history_show
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with my model. 
it used to be

```
class Country < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :people
end
```

Answer (score 5):

I had this issue too, but it wasn't caused by a lost association. I had incorrectly pluralized my model's name when I created it: it was `Things` instead of `Thing`.

I fixed it manually by changing the class name in `things.rb` from `Things` to `Thing` and renaming the file to `thing.rb`.